# Create column of unique values based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have this Dataframe:

```
    NAME           TEST
0   Homer Simpson  PASSED
1   Homer Simpson  FAILED
2   Homer Simpson  FAILED
3   Marge Simpson  PASSED
4   Marge Simpson  PASSED
5    Lisa Simpson  PASSED
6    Bart Simpson  FAILED
7  Maggie Simpson  FAILED
```

And my goal is to create a column containing the values of the TEST column added together based on the NAME column. Like this:

```
    NAME            TEST    RESUME
0   Homer Simpson   PASSED  [PASSED: 1, FAILED: 2]
1   Marge Simpson   PASSED  [PASSED: 2]
3   Lisa Simpson    PASSED  [PASSED: 1]
4   Bart Simpson    FAILED  [FAILED: 1]
5   Maggie Simpson  FAILED  [FAILED: 1]
```

So far, I've used:

```
df.groupby('ID')['TEST'].nunique()
```

But this only adds up the values and what I want is to have the values and how many times they appear for each name.

```
Bart Simpson      1
Homer Simpson     2
Lisa Simpson      1
Maggie Simpson    1
Marge Simpson     1
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
from collections import Counter

out = df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(TEST=('TEST','first'),
                                                         RESUME=('TEST',Counter))
print (out)
             NAME    TEST                      RESUME
0   Homer Simpson  PASSED  {'PASSED': 1, 'FAILED': 2}
1   Marge Simpson  PASSED               {'PASSED': 2}
2    Lisa Simpson  PASSED               {'PASSED': 1}
3    Bart Simpson  FAILED               {'FAILED': 1}
4  Maggie Simpson  FAILED               {'FAILED': 1}
```

For list of joined values:

```
from collections import Counter

f = lambda x: [f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in Counter(x).items()]
df = df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(TEST=('TEST','first'),
                                                        RESUME=('TEST',f))
print (df)
             NAME    TEST                RESUME
0   Homer Simpson  PASSED  [PASSED:1, FAILED:2]
1   Marge Simpson  PASSED            [PASSED:2]
2    Lisa Simpson  PASSED            [PASSED:1]
3    Bart Simpson  FAILED            [FAILED:1]
4  Maggie Simpson  FAILED            [FAILED:1]
```

And for joined strings:

```
from collections import Counter

f = lambda x: ', '.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in Counter(x).items())
df = df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(TEST=('TEST','first'),
                                                        RESUME=('TEST',f))
print (df)
             NAME    TEST              RESUME
0   Homer Simpson  PASSED  PASSED:1, FAILED:2
1   Marge Simpson  PASSED            PASSED:2
2    Lisa Simpson  PASSED            PASSED:1
3    Bart Simpson  FAILED            FAILED:1
4  Maggie Simpson  FAILED            FAILED:1
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use the `Counter` from the `collections` standard library

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False).agg({'TEST':Counter})
```

that makes the 'TEST' column a dictionary values that we can use to implement logic to determine if the student pass or fail

| NAME | TEST |
| --- | --- |
| Bart Simpson | Counter({'FAILED': 1}) |
| Homer Simpson | Counter({'FAILED': 2, 'PASSED': 1}) |
| Lisa Simpson | Counter({'PASSED': 1}) |
| Maggie Simpson | Counter({'FAILED': 1}) |
| Marge Simpson | Counter({'PASSED': 2}) |

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(df[['NAME', 'TEST']].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
 .assign(TEST=lambda d: d['TEST'].add(': '+d['count'].astype(str)))
 .groupby('NAME', as_index=False)['TEST'].agg(', '. join)
)
```

Output:

```
             NAME                  TEST
0    Bart Simpson             FAILED: 1
1   Homer Simpson  FAILED: 2, PASSED: 1
2    Lisa Simpson             PASSED: 1
3  Maggie Simpson             FAILED: 1
4   Marge Simpson             PASSED: 2
```

Or:

```
out = (df[['NAME', 'TEST']]
       .value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
       .assign(count=lambda d: d['TEST'].add(': '+d['count'].astype(str)))
       .groupby('NAME', as_index=False, sort=False)
       .agg(**{'TEST': ('TEST', 'first'),
               'RESULT': ('count', ', '. join)
              })
     )
```

Output:

```
             NAME    TEST                RESULT
0   Homer Simpson  FAILED  FAILED: 2, PASSED: 1
1   Marge Simpson  PASSED             PASSED: 2
2    Bart Simpson  FAILED             FAILED: 1
3    Lisa Simpson  PASSED             PASSED: 1
4  Maggie Simpson  FAILED             FAILED: 1
```